# Add new logic without removing old logic inherited from Openzeppelin contract

Tags: solidity, override

I'm using ERC1155 and I want NFT in my contract that cannot be transferred in a specific condition. If I use override for _transferFrom, It will override new logic, and old logic will be lost. I just want to add some conditions to the function. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you override the function within your contact,

you can use the keyword `super` to call the old logic

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/contracts.html?highlight=super#inheritance

Answer (score 0):

You can create new function in your own contract and make use of interfaces to use ERC-1155 predefined contract functionalities.

For example:

```
function _transferFrom(address owner, address contract1155, address from, address to, uint256 id, uint256 amount, bytes data) public {

require(msg.sender == owner, "Function could be called by owner only");
IERC1155(contract1155).safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 id, uint256 amount, bytes data);

}
```

Here we added our own require check which check whether the call is made by owner of contract or not and then uses erc-1155 method to transfer tokens by extends the erc1155 functionality extended.

'override' keyword is used when we want to preserve the function signature and want to change the logic only.